# Transform intersection type to union type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to get one of the overloaded functions in ts.

I don't know how to do this, but I know how to traverse a union type to get a type in it, and the overloaded function is represented as the intersection of functions, so I want to transform the intersection to a union type.

Transform intersection type to union type in typescript like:

```
type InterscetionToUnion<T> =  T; // impl here

// test case
type intersection = { a: 1 } & { b: 2 };
type test = ExceptTrue<Equals<{ a: 1 } | { b: 2 }, InterscetionToUnion<intersection>>>

type Equals<O1, O2> = (<T>(arg: T extends O1 ? T : T) => void) extends (<T>(arg: T extends O2 ? T : T) => void) ? true : false
type ExceptTrue<T extends true> = T;
```

Does ts allow this? I didn't find a similar problem in [type-challenges](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges).

Comment: This is impossible, as far as I know... nothing I know of will distinguish `{a: 1} & {b: 2}` from `{a: 1; b: 2}` so anything that gives you `{a: 1} | {b : 2}` for the former will also do so for the latter. Do you want me to post answer saying as much?

Comment: @jcalz I'm also looking for the answer to this question