# Transform intersection of functions to union of functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

While browsing I can find answer on how to translate an Union to Intersection - including this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286#50375286) - but is the reverse possible ?

I'd like in order to filter part of a type holding functions to temporarly do domething like

```js
type T = ((a: 1) => 2) & ((a: 1 | 2) => 2)

type IntersectionToUnion<Intersection> = Intersection // do stuff here

type test1 = IntersectionToUnion<T> // desired result: ((a: 1) => 2) | ((a: 1 | 2) => 2)
```

Or given a defintion like so

```js
type U = {
  (a: 1) => 2
  (a: 1 | 2) => 2
}

type TypeToUnion<Type> = Type // do stuff here

type test2 = TypeToUnion<T> // desired result: ((a: 1) => 2) | ((a: 1 | 2) => 2)
```

Is any, or both, `IntersectionToUnion`, `TypeToUnion` achievable ?
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UAUSCGAuKBGAlAgfFAEx4BkyamWUAPsXvISQFDOiRQCSAdsBAE4BnCAGNgASwD23GJICq3KdwA8PPkNETphRGoHCxSqAHpjUACaSog4AFcAZvagALARFbtofG9V299mkqyCkrKMISmFhCC4vwQ5lBxgrYANsCYKBjYDEx4dJlUtPQE9B7g0HIIUADezFDIWbiYRHUNhXQkzcwAvmUcMOXBitJh5Tqw5SZmltZ2ji5ufV7RwERVA5BDoXIR09Gx8YnRqekUjTnF%20ZTYRSQlJEA)

---

Edit Apparently already asked 7 month ago with a comment from jcalz - reliable source if any - stating he does not know hos to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75457935/transform-intersection-type-to-union-type-in-typescript)

I still leave the question as new version of typescript has emerged since then.

But honestly i do not get it - as if i have

```js
type AType = {
  (a: 1): 2
  (a: 2): 2
}

declare const f: AType

f(1) // valid and 1 is infered
f(2) // valid and 2 is infered
```

How come since typescript can infered both defintion of `AType` how is there we can not distinguish between them - and break the type apart ?

Comment: Someone [has asked this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75457935/transform-intersection-type-to-union-type-in-typescript). A comment from jcalz there says it's impossible. He's very reliable about this stuff.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you - hopefully an update of typescript has change this - let's see ;)

Comment: This is not just any "intersection" type, this is "overloads" type

Comment: @Dimava I was wondering about both (intersection and overload)  but your solution works for both ;) (just ducplicate in case of intersection but a bit of cleaning and result is ok)

Comment: The solution doesn't work for "both" unless the intersection happens to be an intersection of call signatures.  You can't, for example, turn `A & B` into `A | B` for *arbitrary* `A` and `B`.  Given `{a: 1} & {b: 2, c: 3}` you cannot programmatically derive `{a: 1} | {b: 2, c: 3}` (to the best of my knowledge).  Is this question specifically about multiple call signatures? If so, please [edit] the question to clarify (e.g., intersection *of functions*).

Comment: I did edit

@jcalz But I've managed to make it work for both by filtering out duplicate that occurs when given an intersection.
If any better soliutions for a Union of **functions** i'de like to read it ;)

Comment: Ment not an union but an intersection of functions or a function overload type
sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work for generics, but splitting overloads is generally possible

```
type SplitOverloads<T> = 
/* ... for every amount of overloads ... */
| T extends {
  (...a: infer A1): infer R1
  (...a: infer A2): infer R2
} ? {
  1: (...a: A1) => R1
  2: (...a: A2) => R2
}
: T extends {
  (...a: infer A1): infer R1
} ? {
  1: (...a: A1) => R1
}
: never


type X = SplitOverloads<U>
//   ^?
// type X = {
//     1: (a: 1) => 2;
//     2: (a: 1 | 2) => 2;
// }
```